# On which checkout step tax gets calculated if tax calculation is based on Billing Address?

Tags: magento2, checkout, tax, billing-address, tax-class

I wanted to understand, on which checkout step, tax gets calculated if tax calculation is based on Billing Address?

Also which class/method gets called and what triggers it when Magento calculates the tax based on billing address?